# Как внутри многомерного массива взять часть другого массива

Tags: php

Есть например вот такой многомерный массив:

```
<?php
class myClass {
    public static $array = [ // главный массив
        ['element1',['a1','b1','c1']], // первый подмассив
        ['element2',['a2','b2','c2']] // второй подмассив
    ];
?>
```

Как вместо массива `['a1','b1','c1']` взять массив `['a2','b2','c2']` ?

Т.е. грубо говоря нужно вот так:

```
<?php
class myClass {
    public static $array = [
        ['element1',myClass::$array[1][1]],
        ['element2',['a2','b2','c2']]
    ];
?>
```

хотя при такой попытке получаю syntax error

Comment: не понятно из вопроса - вам нужно что бы элемент element1 был ключом массива?

Comment: Нет. Мне нужно чтобы место первого массива `['a1','b1','c1']` автоматически заполнял второй массив `['a2','b2','c2']` и чтобы при смене второго первый таким образом тоже менялся автоматически

Comment: если внутри класса, то объявите новый метод, и в теле метода присваивайте вторую часть массива в первую. Если за пределами класса, то можно прямыми обращениями к свойству, т.к. область видимости позволяет:  `myClass::$array[0] = myClass::$array[1];`

`var_dump(myClass::$array);`

Comment: 'element1' и 'element2' т.е. первые части подмассивов должны остаться, работать нужно только со вторыми частями. Напишите как сделать присвоение внутри класса

Answer (score 1):

Внутри класса будет так:

```
class myClass
{    
    public static $array = [
        ['element1', ['a1','b1','c1']],
        ['element2', ['a2','b2','c2']]
    ];

    public static function set_array() {
        self::$array[0][1] = self::$array[1][1];
    }
}

// Это оригинал
var_dump(myClass::$array);

// Этим методом перезаписываем часть массива
myClass::set_array();

// Теперь массив изменён
var_dump(myClass::$array);
```